# Compiling QGIS (with customizations) for Windows

Tags: qgis

I was able to customize a few features of QGIS in Ubuntu. Now I am trying to compile the same code on Windows, by following the installation guide given for Windows. I have downloaded all of the dependencies using OsGeo4W and struck at SIP. I tried setting environment variables to point to sip site-pacakges too ( C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages )
I am using visual studio compiler libraries.

Here is the cmake trace

```
QGIS version: 1.8.0 Lisboa (10800)
Could not find GRASS
Touch support disabled
Found Proj: C:/OSGeo4W/bin/proj.dll
Found GEOS: C:/OSGeo4W/bin/geos_c.dll
Found GDAL: C:/OSGeo4W/bin/gdal18.dll (1.9.2)
Found Spatialindex: C:/OSGeo4W/bin/spatialindex1.dll
Found Qwt: C:/OSGeo4W/bin/qwt5.dll (5.2.1)
Found Sqlite3: C:/OSGeo4W/bin/sqlite3.dll
Found PostgreSQL: C:/OSGeo4W/lib/libpq.lib
Found SpatiaLite: C:/OSGeo4W/bin/spatialite.dll
Pedantic compiler settings enabled
Found Python executable: C:/Python27/python.exe
Found Python version: 2.7
Found Python library: C:/Python27/libs/python27.lib
CMake Error at cmake/FindSIP.cmake:54 (MESSAGE):
  Could not find SIP
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:476 (FIND_PACKAGE)

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using the python shipped with OSGeo4W.  You might find the cmake call in ms-windows/osgeo4w/package.cmd useful - it contains all the options used for the OSGeo4W qgis build.